# Is there a way for pre-setting proxy addresses for specific networks?

Tags: debian, networking, proxy

I'm tired of commenting in and out different proxy acquire lines which located in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy` as I change networks. Is there a way for binding the settings for networks? Iphones have an option like that, but I wonder if I can do it with my computer without writing a script for doing that for me. I've made a little search and checked `man proxy` & `man 10proxy` but they don't exist and couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [pacproxy](https://github.com/otahi/pacproxy) if you are familier with Ruby.
After installation, you can use like as follows.

```
$ bundle exec pacproxy -P ~/proxy.pac -p 3128

$ export $PROXY=localhost:3128
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a network interface goes up or down, scripts in `/etc/network/*.d` are executed.

So for example you could make `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy` a symbolic link whose target gets changed by a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`. These scripts get a few environment variables, in particular `IFACE` with the interface name; you can use `ifconfig`, `route`, `ip`, etc. to obtain information about the network that's being joined. The [`interfaces(5)`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=5) man page documents this facility.